# change value in backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my backbone model I have something like

```
.......

initialize: function() {
  this.on('change', function() {
  console.log('Values changed');
});
},

defaults: {
  pagelocation: "foo",
},
setPageLocation: function(newLocation) {
 this.set({pagelocation: newLocation});
}
................
```

In my view I have

```
showDashBoard: function() {
    this.breadCrumbsModel.setPageLocation('quax');
},
......................
```

For some reason when I look at my model I still get the value `foo` although I changed it to have `quax`

Comment: Is the event `change` fired? Do you see `'Values changed'` in your JS console?

Comment: Yes I see `values changed` in my JS console

Comment: When you say "look at my model" - do you mean on the server?

Comment: the model is not on a server. It is just a field I made up

Comment: Then what do you mean by "look at my model"? Where are you looking? What happens if you look at the event argument that is passed to the "changed" callback?

Comment: Ha! I was thinking the field `pagelocation` in the model. If that is not possible, what would be the best way to set data variables and retrieve them

Comment: When the change event is fired, it contains within it the attributes that were changed. Make sure that the event contains that data.

Comment: it seems, your code is perfect, can you put log after calling setPageLocation 

 `showDashBoard: function() {
    this.breadCrumbsModel.setPageLocation('quax');
    console.log(this.breadCrumbsModel.toJSON()); 
}`

Comment: Maybe you are interested in this library https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder it allows you to have model and view syncronized. If you change a field it will update the model and if you change the model the field will be changed automatically. To do it manually you must listen the both change events in the view and do whatever you need. Field changed -> edit the model , Model changed -> update the field. To see the content of the model you can open the webtools and debug your code. Put a breakpoint in the method setPageLocation and after this.set confirm the change in attributes

Comment: can you try this.set('pagelocation', newlocation) instead?